# What should I do next on my GPG key after my computer is seized by authority?

Tags: gnupg, system-compromise, web-of-trust

Unfortunately, although my keys are protected by password, I am afraid it is not strong enough. I assume I lost control of all my private keys now. I still have backup of my private keys, what I want to know is, for my privacy, should I generate a new sub key from my old master key and revoke the other old subkeys, or I should generate a totolly new key, sign my new key with the old key and then revoke the old key? Additionally, my old key is in the "strong set" of WoT, if I generate a new key, does it mean I need to build the web of trust from start all over again?

Comment: Seems like you have to start over with a new keypair if you don't trust the security of your old password

Comment: Is there any advised way better than work from scratch?